# django admin site change the display label of field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I hope the title is enough to understand what my issue is, I just want to change the default label **Fathers Lastname:** into **Lastname** without changing the table field name in the models

[image]

This is my models.py:

```py
class ParentsProfile(models.Model):
    Fathers_Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Fathers_Middle_Initial = models.CharField("Middle Initial",max_length=500,null=True,blank=True, help_text="Father")
    Fathers_Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding verbose_name

```
Fathers_Firstname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Lastname",max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the label name by adding the first postional attribute to the field.

use the code below:

```
Fathers_Firstname = models.CharField("Lastname",max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create **the custom column "lastname"** with `lastname()` and can rename it with [@admin.display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ParentsProfile

@admin.register(ParentsProfile)
class ParentsProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('lastname',) # ← "lastname()" needs to be assigned  
                                 # ↓ Displayed  
    @admin.display(description='Lastname')
    def lastname(self, obj):
        return obj.Fathers_Firstname
```